# ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'valeurs_actions' for update in FROM clause when deleting from Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

```
mysql> delete from valeurs_actions where id not in
    -> (select * from
    -> (select t1.id from valeurs_actions t1 inner join(select action_id,max(temps_action) as temps_action from valeurs_actions
    ->  group by action_id) as t2
    -> on t1.action_id=t2.action_id and t1.temps_action=t2.temps_action)
    ->  as id_as );
```

I tried to run following delete, but I get  the error : `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'valeurs_actions' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM valeurs_actions v1 -- use different alias here
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT t1.id 
                  FROM   valeurs_actions t1 
                  INNER JOIN(SELECT v2.action_id, 
                                    Max(v2.temps_action) AS temps_action 
                             FROM   valeurs_actions v2 -- and here
                             GROUP  BY v2.action_id
                            ) AS t2 
                          ON t1.action_id = t2.action_id 
                         AND t1.temps_action = t2.temps_action
                  );
```

**NOTE:** you had one aditional `SELECT * FROM` and was unnecesary.

Comment: btw im sure this code can be optimized, but we need some sample data and expected output to do that. But you may create a different question later

Comment: Actually, that "unnecessary" outer `SELECT * FROM` formerly was needed; it worked miracles before Oracle [changed the way the optimizer handles derived tables in 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html#derived-table-optimization). It previously forced the inner query to be materialized into an implicit temporary table before the outer query was fully analyzed, allowing you to reference the same table where you otherwise could not, e.g. `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE c1 IN (SELECT * FROM(SELECT... /* a query returning a single column that also references t1 */) tmp)`